# How to Use decorators in STANDARD SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to recover the truncated data from a table in bigquery an hour back, 
I found one of the solution in legacy SQL like below:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [PROJECT_ID:DATASET.TABLE@-3600000]
```

How to achieve the same in standard sql.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [`FOR SYSTEM TIME AS OF`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#for-system-time-as-of) documentation. You would want something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `project`.dataset.table FOR SYSTEM TIME AS OF
  TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
```

Answer (score 1):

Relative time decorator is not supported in standard sql yet. You can use absolute timestamp as the decorator in standard sql. Link from official Bigquery [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-tables#undeletetable).

**EDIT**

As per Elliott's response, its supported now in standard sql with different syntax.

Comment: Great work Bigquery team !!! I have updated my response to refer to Elliott's response.